# Is there MSHTML Editing equivalent in MS Edge?

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I want to use MS Edge as an html editor.  Is that possible?

Can I use c++ to access undo stack?

If so, please point me to any kind of documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Edge is a web browser, not an HTML editor. This question makes no sense.

Comment: @cody-gray You can turn IE into an html editor, why turning Edge makes no sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any sources for this, but I'm pretty certain that Microsoft didn't carry this functionality over into Edge - especially considering that you can't embed Edge in a C++ or .NET desktop application the same way you can with IE.

I don't see any reason you couldn't just keep using MSHTML, though.

Answer (score 0):

When referring to the MS [Web Browser Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752040(v%3Dvs.85)) documentation there is, at the top of the page:

> We're no longer updating this content regularly. Check the Microsoft Product Lifecycle for information about how this product, service, technology, or API is supported.

And next to it, a button: "Recommended Version."

Click the button, and it's the MS Edge dev portal. From there, we see, amongst others. a link to Mozilla Developer Network Web Docs, and another to MS's own Progressive Web Apps on Windows. Not so MSHTML edity anymore, but if you want it implemented, then perhaps [uservoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/9246885-expose-edgehtml-c-api)?